# How can I manipulate the DOM with the web audio API/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, audio

I'm new to programming and I'm messing around with the Web Audio API. Right now, I have three samples (kick, clap, hihat) that make up a simple drumkit beat when a Play button is pressed.

I want to be able to illustrate this visually on the front end as a sequencer that plays through this drumkit.  For instance, every time the "kick.wav" sample is played, I want to change the color of a div that is associated with it.

My questions are:

1. How do I associate every time a kick, clap or hihat are played with a div in the html?
2. How can I add this association to sequence through when the play button is hit?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
    <button id="play">play</button>

    <script src="javascript/tween.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/shared.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/seq.js"></script>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function playSound(buffer, time) {
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start(time);
}

function loadSounds(obj, soundMap, callback) {
  // Array-ify
  var names = [];
  var paths = [];
  for (var name in soundMap) {
    var path = soundMap[name];
    names.push(name);
    paths.push(path);
  }
  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(context, paths, function(bufferList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bufferList.length; i++) {
      var buffer = bufferList[i];
      var name = names[i];
      obj[name] = buffer;
    }
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  });
  bufferLoader.load();
}

function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
  this.context = context;
  this.urlList = urlList;
  this.onload = callback;
  this.bufferList = new Array();
  this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) {
  // Load buffer asynchronously
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  var loader = this;

  request.onload = function() {
    // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
    loader.context.decodeAudioData(
      request.response,
      function(buffer) {
        if (!buffer) {
          alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
          return;
        }
        loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
        if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
          loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
      }
    );
  }

  request.onerror = function() {
    alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
  }

  request.send();
};

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
  this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
};

var RhythmSample = function() {
  loadSounds(this, {
    kick: 'sounds/kick.wav',
    claps: 'sounds/claps.wav',
    hihat: 'sounds/hihat.wav'
  });
};

RhythmSample.prototype.play = function() {
  // We'll start playing the rhythm 100 milliseconds from "now"
  var startTime = context.currentTime + 0.100;
  var tempo = 120; // BPM (beats per minute)
  var eighthNoteTime = (60 / tempo) / 2;
  var allDivs = document.getElementsByName('colorchangingdivs[]');

  // Play 2 bars of the following:
  for (var bar = 0; bar < 2; bar++) {
    var time = startTime + bar * 8 * eighthNoteTime;
    // Play the bass (kick) drum on beats 1, 5
    playSound(this.kick, time);

    playSound(this.kick, time + 4 * eighthNoteTime);
    console.log("4")
    // Play the snare drum on beats 3, 7
    playSound(this.claps, time + 2 * eighthNoteTime);
    playSound(this.claps, time + 6 * eighthNoteTime);

    // Play the hi-hat every eighthh note.
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      playSound(this.hihat, time + i * eighthNoteTime);
    }
  }
};

var sample = new RhythmSample();

document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('click', function() {
  sample.play();
});
```

THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Change the color of the element you want inside of your playSound() function.

Comment: How would I add that? Would it be a callback function? I have no clue.

Comment: Sorry you will have to do some Googling to figure out the timing, I'm not that familiar with buffering and audio playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another parameter to playSound() that matches the div id of the one you want to color. And logic to change the color when playing the sound, selecting the div by the id you've passed in.

```
function playSound(buffer, time, colorID) {
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start(time);
  document.getElementById(colorID).backgroundColor = blue; //or hex color/rgb value
}
```

Then you just have to add the right parameter when you call playSound.

```
playSound(this.kick, time + 4 * eighthNoteTime,"your-kick-div-id");
```

If you need different colors for different sounds/divs, then just add an if/elseif statement in the background color setting.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for most of it.  How would I associate timing of the div color change, so that when a sound is played on the timeline, the div changes colors too.  Right now, the play button changes the colors of the all associated divs immediately.

Comment: Sorry you will have to do some Googling to figure out the timing, I'm not that familiar with buffering and audio playing.